# Install the same 64-bit packages as a 32-bit Xubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, virtual-machine, vmware, xubuntu

I have been using a virtual machine (Xubuntu 12.10, with VMWare on a windows host) for all my programming work, which I am trying to transition from a 32-bit install to a 64-bit install. I am hoping to be able to automatically re-install all the packages I have been using in the 32-bit VM in my new 64-bit VM.

Reading [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1047072&p=6596530#post6596530), I ran `sudo dpkg --get-selections` to get a list of installed packages, but many of the packages have an `:i386` suffix.

Is there an easy way to install the corresponding 64-bit packages? Am I safe to replace `:i386` with `:x86_64` or something similar in my package listing before trying to install them?

Comment: It seems the suffix I would need is `:amd64`.

Comment: :i386 "should" mean that it's not the native architecture.  So your VM would actually have been x64 and the question is a moot point.

Comment: Would that be the same if I have an x64 CPU in the VM but I used the x86 install disk and so I have a 32-bit kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The first answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6176/how-do-i-upgrade-from-x86-to-x64-without-losing-settings) uses what you suggest, and handles missing packages afterwards. Among the answers some people suggest this is a bad idea. Note as well that if the selection adds a `:i386` it may be because some other package explicitly requires a package for this architecture. If you want to check before, here is a suggestion.

In your system, you should find lists of available packages per repository in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. You could check the list of packages with a :i386 against these lists to ensure that they are present for both i386 and amd64 architectures. The following script is an example of what you could do

```
#!/bin/bash

#iterate on installed packages with a :something in their names
for package in $(
                   dpkg --get-selections | 
                   grep ":" | #comment to check all the selection
                   grep -v deinstall | 
                   cut -f1 |
                   sed s/:.*// | 
                   sort -u
                )
do
  #find all occurences in repository package lists
  grep "Package: $package$" /var/lib/apt/lists/*  2>/dev/null |
    #translation and sources are not usefull
    grep -v Translation |
    grep -v Sources |
    #put the distribution as a prefix
    sed 's/^\(.*\)_dists_\([^_]*\)\(.*\)/\2  \1\3/' |
    #put the architecture difference in the repository file name as a prefix
    sed 's/^\(.*\)-\(amd64\|i386\)_\(.*\)/\2  \1_\3/' |
    #count consecutive identical lines ignoring the architecture prefix
    uniq -c -f1 |
    #print architecture distribution and package if some line is not duplicated
    awk '$1!=2{print $2 " " $3 " " $5}'
done
```

On a lubuntu install this gives me nothing, and on a debian one, the packages `libc6-i686, libwine-bin, libwine-alsa, libwine-gl` are only for i386 architecture for instance

Comment: Thanks! To be clear: this displays a list of the packages installed where there is an i386 version but not amd64 installed [or available?], correct? I get over 500 lines of output (mostly big sets of library packages like Qt, but some "standard" stuff like openjdk).

Comment: Nearly, it just doesn't check installed packages which don't have a specified architecture in `dpkg --get-selections`. You can check for all installed packages by removing the `grep ":" |` line in the filtering of the packages iterated on.

Comment: `openjdk` seems to exist for all of the architectures in my case. Maybe the versions you have come from non-standard repositories, or you don't have both i386 and amd64 repositories installed ? In the last `awk` line you could also print `$4` which contains the address of the repository, and see whether the lines you get come from repositories you don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

This generates a list of the installed packages:

> aptitude search -F '%100p' '~i!~M' > softare-list